# Declare a Function in PHP Using a String?

Tags: php, function

Invalid code:

```
$functionName = 'sayThis';

function $functionName($string) {
    echo $string;
}
```

Can I do anything like this?

Comment: you really don't want to do this. horrible idea.

Comment: Would help to understand why you want to do this. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have the same function (processFormSubmission()) in many files. The function currently has one name, but does several different things depending on the file it is in. Sometimes the same function name can be included in one execution. If this is the case, I get an error saying that the function has already been declared. I want to dynamically name the function so I don't have name clashes. The dynamically assigned name of the function will be stored in a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend you do this, but if you insist, using [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) is an option.
Be extremely careful tho. And keep it far far away from any user input!

```
<?php
$name = 'sayThis';

$code = <<<PHP
function $name(\$string) {
    echo \$string;
}
PHP;
eval($code);

$name('This is NOT a good idea!');
?>
```

Comment: +1 This looks like it answers the OP's question. It is one of those things to be careful what you ask for.

Answer (score 3):

[`call_user_func`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and [`call_user_func_array`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) do something similar.  Use sparingly and judiciously.

Comment: I want to dynamically declare the function name